# Make a ViewGroup clickable on Android

Tags: android

I have a ViewGroup (LinearLayout) which contains a couple of TextViews and one ImageView.
I want to make this entire group clickable.

I tried something like this:

```
    viewGroup.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

However, clicks on the TextViews or ImageViews or on the area enclosed by the ViewGroup above doesn't result in the handler being called.

Any suggestions on how I can make a whole ViewGroup clickable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution was as simple as adding

`android:clickable="true"`

to the xml for the `RelativeLayout` group

Comment: This attribute can also be used with `LinearLayout`. The XML attribute is inherited from the `View`.

Answer (score 3):

Make the layout click-able.  You can make the layout clickable (you might have to use the focus attributes).  Just don't forget to assign an ID to the layout so you can detect it.