# How can I click the outside of widget and the widget dismiss?

Tags: android, onclick, touch-event

The following screenshor is my a part of my project, the gray list I use a listview instead of `popupwindow`.
but I want to realize the effect like `popupwindow` when I click the outside part of popupwindow,the pop will dismiss.
[image]

what I can do for that ,please teach me ,thanks advanced

Comment: you want to show a popup when a user clicks below red marked area.

Comment: no,I want to know how to make the red dismiss when I click the outside part of red

Answer (score 0):

If you make the container for the red area a layout such as `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` fill the screen, then you can make it clickable through XML or programmatically and capture clicks there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244308/make-a-viewgroup-clickable-on-android) is a quick example of how to do this.

This assumes that you just want to dismiss if the white area is clicked.

**Update:** Here is a quick example. This little app will set the white area red if it is clicked. In the click listener, you can easily do what you need to to dismiss the red area.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Set onClick and clickable here to capture clicks. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="layoutClicked"
    tools:context="com.example.layout2.MainActivity">

    <!--Set clickable here, too, to capture clicks so they don't propagate
    to underlying view. The button is still enabled, though. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:clickable="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the supporting code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void layoutClicked(View view) {
    // Set the background color of the "outside" area to red.
    // This is where you would dismiss the red area.
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFDD0000);
    }
}
```

Comment: your mean is that  add the clickable in the red area parent group? I add and it doesn't wor, I want to click the white part and the red area dismiss

Comment: I try, and only I click the top,the red area will dismiss ,and I click the behind of the red area ,it will not dismiss

Comment: @Jsonzhang If you click the white area below the red outlined area, the `onClick` handler will get control and you can dismiss the red area in the `onClick` handler. If you are asking how to dismiss the `ListView` you could [set its visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) to `gone`.